# Nest cannot create the AuthModule instance

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs, circular-dependency, sequelize-typescript

when trying to establish links between the user model and the group, an error occurs:

I can't understand why..

```
[Nest] 30312  - 06.12.2021, 20:53:42     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 30312  - 06.12.2021, 20:53:42   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest cannot create the AuthModule instance.
The module at index [1] of the AuthModule "imports" array is undefined.

Potential causes:
- A circular dependency between modules. Use forwardRef() to avoid it. Read more: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency
- The module at index [1] is of type "undefined". Check your import statements and the type of the module.

Scope [AppModule]
Error: Nest cannot create the AuthModule instance.
The module at index [1] of the AuthModule "imports" array is undefined.
```

app.module.ts https://pastebin.com/T9EC05gS

users.module.ts https://pastebin.com/inS044Xk

user.model.ts https://pastebin.com/wpyUs2SW

groups.module.ts https://pastebin.com/Jvr2Fuk3

group.model.ts https://pastebin.com/nBvkaEUt

auth.module.ts https://pastebin.com/MYQ2dw6y

auth.guard.ts https://pastebin.com/xDpQ8vwE

auth.service.ts https://pastebin.com/G9TzN3XF

Thanks in advance

UPD:
error appears when adding

```
  @Expose()
  @HasMany(() => Group)
  groups: Group[];
```

to user.model.ts

Comment: It's best to add actual code snippets rather than links to code. While the links can give some extra context, they're not searchable within the question's context, which makes the question harder to find

Comment: I wanted to add the code this way (right into the question), but the site said that there is a lot of code in the question ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `auth.module.ts` file, instead of
`import { UsersModule } from '../users';`
try
`import { UsersModule } from '../users/user.module';`

I believe that these barrel files (`index.ts` exporting everything) isn't a good pattern to follow here as it introduces circular imports between NestJS modules.

---

*1* `auth.module.ts` imports `users/index.ts` (which exports `user.module.ts` I guess)
*2* `groups.module.ts` imports `auth/index.ts`  (which exports `auth.module.ts` I guess)
*3* `user.model.ts` imports `groups/index.ts`

then you'll end up with *1* importing *3* and *3* importing *1*. That's the problem.